# Laravel returns "419 PAGE EXPIRED;" After Signin/Register on Chrome & Edge browser etc

Tags: php, laravel, migration, cpanel

After migrating Laravel project Domain (.in to .institute) & Hosting (namecheap to name.com), everything works fine. When I tried to Login or Signup on Chrome & Edge etc. browser, it returns "419 PAGE EXPIRED" error. But when I tried to Login or Signup on DuckDuckGo etc. browser, then it works fine. I tried to clean cache, config, generate:keys, checked & changed csrf token, fixed SSL & etc. every solution what I have found over the internet. But none of solve these issues. What else I can do!

#View

```
@section('title', 'Login')
@include('theme.head')

@include('admin.message')

<!-- end head -->
<!-- body start-->
<body>
<!-- top-nav bar start-->
<section id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar-main-block nav-bar-main-block-one">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-4">
                <div class="nav-bar-btn">
                    <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Home"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>{{ __('frontstaticword.Backtohome') }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-4">
                <div class="logo text-center">
                    @php
                        $logo = App\Setting::first();
                    @endphp

                    @if($logo->logo_type == 'L')
                        <a href="{{ url('/') }}" title="logo"><img src="{{ asset('images/logo/'.$logo->logo) }}" class="img-fluid" alt="logo"></a>
                    @else()
                        <a href="{{ url('/') }}"><b><div class="logotext">{{ $logo->project_title }}</div></b></a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-4">
                <div class="Login-btn txt-rgt">
                    <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="btn btn-primary" title="signup">{{ __('frontstaticword.Signup') }}</a>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- top-nav bar end-->
<!-- Signup start-->
<section id="signup" class="signup-block-main-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <div class="signup-heading">
                {{ __('frontstaticword.LogIntoYour') }} {{ $project_title }} {{ __('frontstaticword.Account') }}!
            </div>

            <div class="signup-block">

                <div class="signin-link btm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        @if($gsetting->fb_login_enable == 1)
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <a href="{{ url('/auth/facebook') }}" title="facebook" class="btn btn-info btm-10" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>{{ __('frontstaticword.ContinuewithFacebook') }}</a>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        @if($gsetting->google_login_enable == 1)
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="google">
                                <a href="{{ url('/auth/google') }}" title="google" class="btn btn-white btm-10" title="google"><i class="fab fa-google"></i>{{ __('frontstaticword.ContinuewithGoogle') }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        @if($gsetting->amazon_enable == 1)
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="signin-link amazon-button">
                                <a href="{{ url('/auth/amazon') }}" title="amazon" class="btn btn-info btm-10" title="Amazon"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i>{{ __('frontstaticword.ContinuewithAmazon') }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        @if($gsetting->linkedin_enable == 1)
                        <div class="col-lg-6"> 
                            <div class="signin-link linkedin-button">
                                <a href="{{ url('/auth/linkedin') }}" title="linkedin" class="btn btn-info btm-10" title="Linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>{{ __('frontstaticword.ContinuewithLinkedin') }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        @if($gsetting->twitter_enable == 1)
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="signin-link twitter-button">
                                <a href="{{ url('/auth/twitter') }}" title="twitter" class="btn btn-info btm-10" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>{{ __('frontstaticword.ContinuewithTwitter') }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        @if($gsetting->gitlab_login_enable == 1)
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="signin-link btm-10">
                                <a href="{{ url('/auth/gitlab') }}" title="gitlab" class="btn btn-white" title="gitlab"><i class="fab fa-gitlab"></i>{{ __('frontstaticword.ContinuewithGitLab') }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    

                <form method="POST" class="signup-form" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    @csrf
                 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="Enter Your E-Mail"   name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="Enter Your Password" name="password" required>

                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">                       
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                            <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('frontstaticword.Login') }}
                        </button>
                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <div class="forgot-password text-center btm-20"><a href="{{ 'password/reset' }}" title="sign-up">{{ __('frontstaticword.ForgotPassword') }}</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="signin-link text-center btm-20">
                       {{ __('frontstaticword.Bysigningup') }} <a href="{{url('terms_condition')}}" title="Policy">{{ __('frontstaticword.Terms&Condition') }} </a>, <a href="{{url('privacy_policy')}}" title="Policy">{{ __('frontstaticword.PrivacyPolicy') }}.</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="sign-up text-center">{{ __('frontstaticword.Donothaveanaccount') }}?<a href="{{ route('register') }}" title="sign-up"> {{ __('frontstaticword.Signup') }}</a>
                    </div>
                            
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
<!--  Signup end-->
<!-- jquery -->
@include('theme.scripts')
<!-- end jquery -->
</body>
<!-- body end -->
</html>
```

#Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use Socialite;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Contracts\Activity;
use App\Setting;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public function authenticated()
    {

        $gsetting = Setting::first();

        if( Auth::User()->role == "instructor" || Auth::User()->role == "user")
        {

            if(isset($gsetting->activity_enable))
            {
                if($gsetting->activity_enable == '1')
                {
                    $project = new User();

                    activity()
                       ->useLog('Login')
                       ->performedOn($project)
                       ->causedBy(auth()->user())
                       ->withProperties(['customProperty' => 'Login'])
                       ->log('Logged In')
                       ->subject('Login');

                }
            }

        }

        

        if (Auth::User()->status == 1)
        {
           
            if( Auth::User()->role == "admin") 
            {
                // do your magic here
                return redirect()->route('admin.index');
            }
            elseif( Auth::User()->role == "instructor")
            {

                return redirect()->route('instructor.index');

            }
            else
            {

                return redirect('/home');
      
            }
        }
        else{
            
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('delete','You are deactivated !'); 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function socialLogin($social)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($social)->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback($social)
    {
        $userSocial = Socialite::driver($social)->user();
        $user = User::where(['email' => $userSocial->getEmail()])->first();

        // set the remember me cookie if the user check the box
        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;

        // attempt to do the login
       

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->get('email') , 'password' => $request->get('password') ,
        'status' => 1], $request->remember)){
        
                return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }
        else
        {
            $errors = new MessageBag(['email' => ['Email or password is invalid.']]);
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput($request->except('password'));
        }



        if ($user) {
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect()-> action('HomeController@index');
        }
        else {
            return view('auth.register', ['name'=> $userSocial->getName(), 
                                            'email' => $userSocial->getEmail()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found 'same_site' => "none" in config session file, instead of null. After changed none to null, it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I upgrade from laravel 7 to 8 and the `session.php` `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE` has the default on `true`

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),
```

put the `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false` on the `.env` because on local don't have SSL and then run:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

(the regular cache clear don't do the job)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this directive, you should remove it.

I've had this problem before (Laravel 5x) and it was solved after I removed it.

`$request->session()->flush();`

This directive makes the csrf = empty.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions work, check if you have set these two variables in your local .env

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=
SESSION_DOMAIN=
```

In my case, I tried Sanctum for authentication, but ended up switching to a different authentication method. I forgot to remove two variables in my local .env file that I just set for testing purposes.

Even though my localhost 127.0.0.1:8000 was part of SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS i kept getting the "419 Page Expired" error message when trying to login.

And also in my case everything worked online (because those variables weren't set there either)