# Laravel 10 session issues - fails to login sometimes except using incognito mode

Tags: authentication, session-cookies, laravel-10

I have laravel project built on **laravel 10**.
Sometimes I can login, and at times I can't except I use another browser or incognito mode.
I tried clearing cache, delete sessions from the database table, and setting values in the config/session.php but nothing seems to work.

**I am storing my sessions in database instead of file.**

The issue refuses to go away.

**Here is my session.php file content**

```
 env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),



    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

I have tried following the instructions here

[Laravel returns "419 PAGE EXPIRED;" After Signin/Register on Chrome & Edge browser etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543908/laravel-returns-419-page-expired-after-signin-register-on-chrome-edge-brows)

And here

[Artisan command for clearing all session data in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732321/artisan-command-for-clearing-all-session-data-in-laravel)

But none seems to solve the problem.